# subclass of uitableviewcontroller static cell not dispalying

Tags: uitableview, xcode6, autolayout, interface-builder

secondTBLVControllert <- FirstTableVC <- UITableVC

In secondTBLVControllert i am not getting tableview and its cell, in this class i have used static cells and style is group, i have set datasource and delegate in IB and code also... Im using storyboard.

and i have tried by implementing and without implementing delegate and datasource methods.

```
  import Foundation
  import UIKit
  class secondTBLVControllert : FirstTableVC {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
  }
```

i am getting empty view.. i am not getting my designs

Comment: Perhaps you missed setting the scene's custom class to secondTBLVControllert?

Comment: you mean setting the class name(secondTBLVControllert) in interfacebuler? but i have done